# GAMEMAKER 2.o Increasing timer after press a button

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

How do i make a decreasing timer after pressing some button? Actually trying to maker in step event but the timer only decreases 1 per times which the button was pressed.

Comment: Can you show the code of what you've tried? If it's in the step event, but only decreases once a time, then I'm wondering how the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Just judging the functionality from the given information: you've set the timer in an event that you can only reach when a button is pressed.

If it only happens when you press the button, then that means the timer will only decrease if you either hold the button or click the button repeately.

A possible solution is to make a new boolean, and set that boolean to 'true' when the button is pressed. Then you make a new statement that checks if the boolean is true, and put the timer inside that statement.

Hopefully this helps.